# How to clean system data memory on Mac after I imported large sql file to mysql, which filled it up?

Tags: mysql, memory, system

Recently I imported large sql file 33 gb into mysql and after that I saw that system data on my Mac became huge (over 150 gb). I tried CleanMyMac, but it was able to clean small stuff from system data.

My Mac's storage

[image: 1]

Comment: Hello, have you found a solution for this? I have the same problem with MySQL 8

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by deleting SQL server from my computer. The storage emptied immediately after that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Many leftover folders from installing and uninstalling programs or accumulated cache data can take up a significant amount of system data.
I have developed an app that searches and finds the size of all folders, which will be very helpful in managing storage space.
I was able to reduce my system data from 120GB to 30GB.

The app is called cancerFinder.

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/cancerfinder/id6446483815?mt=12